# different output from the crypt function

Tags: c, output, crypt

Getting 2 different from exact same keys passed to crypt function in C.

File #1 : crack.c, 
Input in crack.c

```
string HashedPassword;
string Hash = argv[1];
char Salt[2];
Salt[0] = Hash[0];
Salt[1] = Hash[1];
char Key1 = 'a';

int Counter = 1;
    do
    {
        HashedPassword = crypt(&Key1, Salt); `Creates Hashed password from Key1 & stores in Variable Hashed password`
        printf("key1 value is :%c & hashed Password is : %s\n", Key1, HashedPassword);
        if(strcmp(Hash, HashedPassword) == 0) `Compares if Hash entered by user matches the Hashed password created from Key1`
        {
            printf("%c\n", Key1); `prints the value stored in key1 if the hashed password made from Key1 matches the hash entered by user`
            return 0;
        }
        Key1++;
        Counter++;
    }
    while( Counter <= 26 );

 Ouput from crack.c
 ~/workspace/pset2/crack/ $ ./crack 50OqznXGVcOJU
 key1 value is :a & hashed Password is : 506RGmWzsA7ws
 key1 value is :b & hashed Password is : 50YG8tFx67moY
 key1 value is :c & hashed Password is : 50Ebw7/ICYLEY
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

=========

File #2 : test2.c,
Input in test2.c

```
int main()
{
char Key1 = 'a';
string HashedPassword;

HashedPassword = crypt(&Key1, "50"); `Creates Hashed password from Key1 & stores in Variable Hashed password`

printf("key1 value is :%c & hashed Password is : %s\n", Key1,  HashedPassword); `Prints the value of Key1 & hash created by crypt function`

printf("%s", HashedPassword);

}
```

/*ignore the line in slashes asdasad,kfanlkfdsnjn,m
kdsafnn
nmksdfl
sdlkasdjaslkdhaslkdjahskj */

```
Ouput from test2.c `Output for test.c`
~/workspace/ $ ./test2
key1 value is :a & hashed Password is : 50OqznXGVcOJU 
50OqznXGVcOJU~/workspace/ $
```

Comment: The key is not 'a', it's 'a' followed by whatever garbage there happens to be up until the next '\0'

Comment: i have no idea what `string` is, but `crypt` needs to be called with a null terminated string.  &Key1 is not.

Comment: Why `C` flag here ? There is not Type called `string` in C, Pls edit the flag

Comment: @ThiruShetty -- I'm guessing string is a typedef for char *.  But I don't know.

Comment: @MFisherKDX if you assume like that, I don't how the hell the code works. Let's wait for #itsHoney to respond.

Comment: @ThiruShetty I assume because it won't compile as std::string due to strcmp. <shrug>

Comment: Actually, This is a program (crack) to submitted, its from edx course.but having difficulty at this stage. why the same variable outputs 2 different hashes. @MFisherKDX

Comment: @ThiruShetty my apologies, didn't realize at 1st.  its a predefined variable made by MIT, this is from edx course. header file is <cs50.h>

Comment: @immibis Thanks. mentioning the null terminator gave me an idea. Here's what i did. It did my job.

char Key1[2] = {'a', '\0'};


    int Counter = 1;

        do
        {
            HashedPassword = crypt(Key1, Salt);